# Images not displaying on page reload

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I searched every where to find the solution for this, but no luck-:( Hope I will get some help here.
I have a Jsp page  with a submit button. when I first time load this page all CSS and images work fine. Onclick submit button reloads the same page with a javascript success alert message. During that second load the page comes back with alert message but i dont see any images or css on my page.

I am not sure if it is IE problem or my code.I tested that page in Firefox, it works fine.

I am using IE8. 
Plase help!

Edit/Update

For some reason, the images display correctly on other pages of my webpages for both IE and FF but not on the page in question. Even I checked my code in my co-workers computer everything is working fine even that page in question.
I guess it something IE doesn't like in my computer. 
please suggest. here is my HTML code

Edit/Update: thanks everyone..I found the solution it was my java code where my session was getting invalidated, causing the images not load. I removed my HTML code from here, as it is not necessary any more.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Could the success message be stopping the rest of the page from loading? Or are there any console errors?

Comment: Check your network tab in your developer tools to see if the CSS file and images are being retrieved.

Comment: @Apohl, page is loading with no error. but when i right click the image to check the property, it says 'not available'.

Comment: yes, images are being retrieved in the developers tool.

Comment: not sure how to post the code, text is too big.